# How do I get to the upper ridges in summerlands South in Ni No Kuni?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

How do I get up to the upper mesas in the desert in summerlands South? Various game guides mention to use ramps but I can't seem to find how to get there. Do I need to wait until a certain point in the story (I've just completed the temple of trials)?.

Answer (score 1):

There are two sets of Mesas in the desert. If you are talking about the northern ones that surround the Temple of Trials then you need the "Airship" that you get after a certain point in the story.  The Mesas that have a ramp are in the southern part of the desert.